# how to show edit and delete button at the right side of a gridview not at left in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want edit and delete button on the right side of the gridview not
   at left side of grid. for user friendly manipulation of gridview.
 how to show buttons at right side of my grid view?
[image: screenshot]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvAllTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
        CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GvAllTasks_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GvAllTasks_RowDeleting" 
        onrowediting="GvAllTasks_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GvAllTasks_RowUpdating" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found">
```

Comment: You can arrange the sequence of your columns in the Grid by doing AutoGenrateColumns="false" and write new sequence of column in the column tag <Columns> </Columns> of grid. refer this http://forums.asp.net/t/1196393.aspx?Autogenerate+Editbutton+on+right+side+placement+help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set **AutoGenerateColumns** property false and create the required columns for the grid using  property within the html source of the grid in whatever order you want. The columns can be pre defined columns like CheckBoxField, ImageField etc. or templatecolumns. The following example shows creating a grid with edit and delete buttons on right for a table with name DEPT having three columns DEPTNO, DNAME and LOC.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvDept" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowFooter="true"style="z-index: 1; left: 145px; top: 22px;position:
absolute; height: 191px; width: 756px;font-family: 'Arial Black'; 
font-size: large" EnableViewState="False">
<Columns>                       
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deptno">
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LblDno" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("Deptno") %>' />                              
         </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>             
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LblDname" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("Dname") %>' />                              
         </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="LblLoc" runat="server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("Loc") %>' />                              
         </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>                          
   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
             <ItemTemplate>                     
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"                           
                     CommandName="Edit" />&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkDelete" runat="server" 
                     Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />&nbsp;            
             </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>             
   </Columns>     
  </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

for adding edit and delete buttons left side of ur gridview add

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

in your columns after your template field

```
    CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" 
    onrowcancelingedit="GvAllTasks_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="GvAllTasks_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="GvAllTasks_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GvAllTasks_RowUpdating" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found">
   <%--  AutoGenerateEditButton="true"--%>
 <%--    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" --%>

    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddTaskid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("task_Id") %>' />
                <%#Eval("task_Id")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("task_Name")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned To">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("task_Employee_Name")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("task_Project_Title")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("task_Status")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Text='<%#"Status : " + Eval("task_Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Gv_DdlStatus" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="-Change Status-" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Reviewed" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="InProgress" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Stopped" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddstatusId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("task_Status") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Start dt">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("task_StartDate")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Completed dt">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("TaskCompletedDt")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>

               <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskCompletedDt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaskCompletedDt") %>'>
              </asp:TextBox>

            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned By">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("AssignedBy")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("comment")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
              <EditItemTemplate>

               <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comment") %>'>
              </asp:TextBox>

            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />


    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```